# Is there any way of updating a MFC app similar to ApplicationDeployment class without .NET?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, installation, updates

I want to make an app update itself programmatically, similar to what ApplicationDeployment class does, but without .NET. The **app has to stop and install the update**. How can I do that?

Comment: MFC is a framework, not a platform. You have to implement this yourself. A possible solution would be to implement and compile the updater application and embed it as a resource into your application. When you want to update your application, extract the updater, create the updater process, and terminate the application.

Comment: I already have the updater integrated in my app, as I use it for other updates as well, but I need the app to stop when the update is for itself, install it and then start the app again. I was hoping there's some mechanism to ask Windows to do it.